# Horizontal Scroll menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My menu will display based on the My SQL DATABASE using ul li. Currently there are six menus visible in the website. while I increase my menu more than six, It has to show in scroll like image slider with previous and next button options. So that the menu will get scrolled horizontally.

One important point is, next button should be visible only if the menu increases more than six. Otherwise next or previous button should not show.

Let me know if i can able to get any script or html code for this.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to set `overflow-y: scroll` in CSS

Comment: I need code with next and previous button option like sliders

Comment: You can see My Demo Page hope this should be help you @senthilkumar

Answer (score 1):

hope this should be help you see link

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ivinraj/vac9x/58/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.right').click(function () {
        var position = $('.container').position();
        var r=position.left-$(window).width()
        $('.container').animate({
            'left': ''+r+'px'
        });
    });    

    $('.left').click(function () {
        var position = $('.container').position();
        var l=position.left+$(window).width()
        if(l<=0)
        {
        $('.container').animate({
            'left': ''+l+'px'
        });
        }
    });    
});
```

[SEE THE FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/kzQFQ/570/)

Comment: Thank you Ivin. But it should not scroll continuously. Because I have to use it for menus. So It should get stopped in last div or li.