# horizontal scrolling text menu with control

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm going to create horizontal scrolling menu with control when its big

like http://www.msn.com/ top text menu. i was looking to find some code like this but i couldn't anyone can help me to find something slimier to this .

[image]

```
<ul id="myUl">
<li> | </li>
<li style="color: red">Espresso</li>
<li style="color: orange">Cappuccino</li>
<li style="color: yellow">American</li>
<li style="color: green">Tea</li>
<li style="color: black">Milk</li>
<li style="color: blue">Juice</li>
<li> | </li>
```

Comment: Something slimier to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont exactly know *how* and *what* you want. But I've created an example [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ivinraj/vac9x/58/). Please come back to me *how* you *exactly* want it based on the example I made so I can improve the example.

Also found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/kzQFQ/570/) `<- this one is what you're lookin for I think, I can make an example with your text if you prefer, even tho you can do that yourself aswell`

Both examples found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883215/horizontal-scroll-menu?rq=1)

You can also take a look [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage) for educational purposes.

Goodluck!

EDIT:

[MADE AN EXAMPLE FOR YOU](http://jsfiddle.net/kzQFQ/666/)

Comment: i update with image its  horizontal scrolling menu in msn

Comment: isn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/kzQFQ/570/) what you're looking for if you place your names _cappuccino / tea etc_ inside of the `<div class="contentContainer blue"></div>` like this : `<div class="contentContainer red">Espresso</div>`

Comment: No problem @AmalPrasad [this one is a little edited with css maybe the way you prefer it more or not](http://jsfiddle.net/kzQFQ/666/)

Comment: is there any way to stop scrolling when last text reach?

Comment: @AmalPrasad maybe try to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068664/how-to-detect-the-end-of-a-horizontal-scroll-in-a-div)